# Do I need to build the whole project every time if I wrote a blog or doc when using Docusaurus?

Tags: deployment, build, blogs, docusaurus

I think it's crazy to build and re-deploy the whole project when I just changed a word in my blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
That's the idea to use a static website generator.

You are offloading the work of publishing an article/blog offline.

You can setup github action which does that on commit and deploys the website for you.